# How to set a fixed and proper Sequence Length in the Sentiment Analysis using LSTM?

Tags: machine-learning, text, nlp, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am working on a Sentiment Classification problem, and as many of you guys know that we have to do pre-processing of the text in order to feed it into word embedding layers. So, accordingly, in the first few pre-processing steps, I encounter that after doing some pre-processing to the data, I have to set a sequence-length that the data will lie within. If the review text line is somehow smaller than the sequence-length, then we will have to pad it and if greater than sequence-length, then we have to truncate it to sequence-length.
But what should be the optimal value for this sequence-length? In many posts it is 200, 100 and even if I put 50, it works. This is my code -

```
def pad_features(reviews_int, sequence_length):

  features = np.zeros((len(reviews_int), sequence_length), dtype = int)

  for i, review in enumerate(reviews_int):

    reviews_len = len(review)

    if reviews_len <= sequence_length:
      zeroes = list(np.zeros(sequence_length - reviews_len))
      new = zeroes + review

    elif reviews_len > sequence_length:
      new = review[0:sequence_length]

    features[i, :] = np.array(new)

  return features
```

```
sequence_length = 100

features = pad_features(reviews_int, sequence_length = sequence_length)

#assert len(features)==len(reviews_int)
#assert len(features[0])==sequence_length

print (features[:10,:10])
```

I am confused now. Can you please help in choosing a right and optimal  Sequence-length? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can have a look at this post: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26366/training-an-rnn-with-examples-of-different-lengths-in-keras

Answer (score 3):

I will be assuming that you are implementing either a Keras or TensorFlow RNN in this answer, but really any other tool applies as well.

First thing to mention is that you are not always forced to select a single sequence length. By defining the appropriate timesteps dimension of the input shape in your neural network as `None`, you can have varying sequence lengths **between** different batches. The only restriction is that the sequence length **within** a single batch will have to be equivalent, and this is because of the predefined shape property of Tensors. Hence, you can feed in batches of say 50, 100, and 150 lengths of sequences to your neural network and see how it performs.

However, setting a single sequence length is often preferred as it's more intuitive and easier to work with. You can simply train different models where the only changing variable is sequence length, and compare their validation accuracy. Different tasks will have different optimal sequence lengths: sentiment analysis may be performed with shorter sequence lengths whereas language models are generally performed with longer sequence lengths. A safe approach would be to take the **median** sequence length of your dataset.

A perhaps safer approach is to either take the **maximum** sequence length, or a sequence length that doesn't result in a lot sentences getting truncated. However, this depends on your architecture. This approach will potentially work better with a concept like **Convolutional RNNs** (Kim et. al., 2014) where we use sliding windows to go over the sequence in short timesteps (3, 5, etc.) just like we would to a image with CNNs. Another potential direction is the **local attention mechanism** (Luong et. al., 2015), which adaptively focuses on a distinct subset of the hidden states derived from the input sequences. Then again, the sequence length is obviously a parameter to experiment with and we can't have a definite answer.